# How do I export Apple Developer Id Certificate without using Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, certificate

I have an Apple Developer certificate that I use to sign my application

```
/usr/bin/codesign --sign "Developer ID Application: P Taylor" --force --deep --verbose /Applications/SongKong.app
```

and I originally used **Xcode** to configure this, but I don't use Xcode for my actual development because this is a cross platform Java application

I now need to setup a new computer as my build computer and need to transfer this developer certificate to the new machine. The advice seems to be to use Xcode, however when I try to run Xcode I get the error

**You cannot use version of the application "Xcode" with this version of OSX, You have Xcode "5.0.1"**

this computer is from 2009, but currently running El Capitan (10.11.6)

So can I export these certificates without having to get Xcode working

Comment: No need for Xcode, just Use `Keychain` app.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini i did this first but couldn't see the developer id, maybe I have the wrong keychain

Comment: ah yes I do, thankyoiu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**Keychain Access.app**](https://support.apple.com/guide/keychain-access/what-is-keychain-access-kyca1083/mac) to **export** any kind of certificate you have in installed in you mac. And also to **import** them in the new system.

This article is helpful: See [**Exporting Manually**](https://ioscodesigning.com/exporting-code-signing-files/#exporting-manually) section

Comment: It's vital that the exported certificate also include the corresponding private key. To get this, be sure to use the "My Certificates" category (bottom left of the Keychain Access window), and export in .p12 format (*not* plain Certificate / .cer).

Comment: Okay ll following this, its quite confusing I tried just copying my keychain to my new computer and then using addKeyChain, I thought it had worked but had no effect on on my code signing which failed with unable to find :(

Comment: Did you follow @GordonDavisson advice ?

Comment: I havent followed your/gordons advice yet I was referring to me just trying to copy and import keychain

Comment: Thanks Gordon, simply following your advice did the trick that was all I had to do. Right now I need to work out how to notarize the app :(